# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory Apache Ignite

Tags: jvm, ignite

Recently we moved to 64 bit JVM with ignite 2.10.0, our cache configuration looks like following (was working alright with 2.9.0),

```
_cfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
{                           
    IgniteInstanceName = MKT_TICK_DATA_CACHE,                               
    DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
    {
        LocalPort = 48500,
        LocalPortRange = 60,
        IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder
        {
            Endpoints = new[] { "127.0.0.1:48500..48560" }
        }
    },
    CommunicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi
    {
        LocalPort = 48100
    },
    DataStorageConfiguration = new DataStorageConfiguration
    {
        DefaultDataRegionConfiguration = new DataRegionConfiguration
        {
            Name = MKT_TICK_DATA_CACHE,
            InitialSize = 500L * 1024 * 1024,
            MaxSize =     4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
            PersistenceEnabled = false,
            PageEvictionMode = Apache.Ignite.Core.Configuration.DataPageEvictionMode.Random2Lru
        },
        SystemRegionInitialSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024
    },
    ClientConnectorConfiguration = new ClientConnectorConfiguration
    {
        // Set a port range from 10000 to 10005
        Port = 10800,
        PortRange = 60,
        HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        IdleTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
        MaxOpenCursorsPerConnection = 10000,
        SocketReceiveBufferSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024,
        SocketSendBufferSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024,
        TcpNoDelay = true,
        ThinClientEnabled = true,
        ThreadPoolSize = 256
    },
    JvmOptions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<String>() { "-Xms1g", "-Xmx20g", "-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC", "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC", "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true", "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=30G" }
    //JvmOptions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<String>() { "-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC", "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC", "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" }
    //JvmOptions = new[] { "-Xmx10g" },//, "-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC", "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC" }
};

_cfg.ServiceThreadPoolSize = 256;
_cfg.SystemThreadPoolSize = 128;
_cfg.StripedThreadPoolSize = 128;
_cfg.WorkDirectory = _dir;
var cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration
{
    Name = MKT_TICK_DATA_CACHE,
    CacheMode = CacheMode.Partitioned,
    Backups = 0,                            
    AtomicityMode = CacheAtomicityMode.Atomic,
    LoadPreviousValue = false,
    OnheapCacheEnabled = true,
    WriteBehindEnabled = false,
    WriteSynchronizationMode = CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FullAsync,
    MaxConcurrentAsyncOperations = 300000
};
_cfg.CacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration[] { cacheConfig };
Ignition.ClientMode = false;
var ignite = Ignition.Start(_cfg);
_cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<Int32, MarketTickS>(MKT_TICK_DATA_CACHE);
_oCache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<Int64, byte[]>(ORION_L_CACHE);
_oSecCache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<Int64, CacheSecurity>(ORION_SEC_CACHE);
```

our cache crashes about 15 mins of running. Role of this cache is to store tick data from market, which is coming in rate @ 60K ticks per second.

```
[14:03:01,528][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-13-#197%QTICKDATA%][] JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory]]
```

Could you help please?

*********** Update ******************************

Updates, after a JDK reinstall on the server. Crash did not happen after 60 minutes of continuous operation. However, still curious Ignite 2.9 takes 3.X GB total ram, but ignite 2.10 takes 32.x GB total ram with same cache configurations (Same set of C# binaries, except ignite with 32.x GB memory is 2.10, and with 3.x GB memory is 2.9). Snap shots attached below,

[image: Ignite 2.10 - Task Manager]

with 2.9,
[image: Ignite 2.9 - Task Manager]

Comment: Can you use:   Use: -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=..
   to determine where the memory is being utilized.

Comment: Sure, I've appened these to my jvmoptions: JvmOptions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<String>() { "-Xms1G", "-Xmx10G", "-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC", "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC", "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true",
                                                                                            "-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=30G", "-XX:HeapDumpPath=C\\Logs" }, will post my findings here.

Comment: after JDK reinstall, there is no more crash, but if you notice (memory on ignite 2.10 is more than 30 gb, with the same data source, and cache code). If there any other logs that I could send over, please let me know. Or if there is any configuration changes to be done for Ignite 2.10.0x?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` switch, it is known to interfere with direct buffer memory allocation, and therefore no longer recommended.

Not sure why it takes more RAM than before, need more details.

Comment: Sure, I will check that right away. What details do you need? Good thing is, it not crashing any more.

Comment: no changes with DisableExplicitGC, Still same 30GB ram usage with 2.10.

Comment: Can you share a reproducer project which uses 3G on 2.9 but 30G on 2.10? I would check it and file a ticket, or provide feedback.

Comment: in order to get you a working module, would require high speed exchange feed, technically not so feasible, however, I can generate and provide any detailed logs that you may need. I would like to reemphasize on the fact, our C# binaries are same for both the versions.

Comment: Please share the "Metrics for local node" message if you have one. You may put it in the question.

Comment: Sure, exchange is closed now. I will share that first thing in the morning tomm. By the way, with metrics you mean, file ignite.log that is generated, it's big file, not sure if question itself will accept that long text? or can it be accepted user@ignite.apache.org here? I can send the detailed log generated this morning.

Comment: user@ignite.apache.org doesn't appear to a valid email address. I tried sending emails from Gmail, it gets dropped. I've uploaded it to: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1T2SimTybcDeccgXqkmfQdzDLkKLpZ-fE?usp=sharing 

ignite-ad8299e9.0 has details with crash. Ram usage went beyond 34 GB, and JVM crashed. Other log is with no crash, with normal run, ram usage 32+ gb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232217/discussion-between-vinay-dwivedi-and-alamar).

Comment: You are running your JVM with  `-Xmx20g, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=30G`. Why are you wondering that JVM uses up that memory that you have allowed? I can still see `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` there.

Comment: Same setting is applied on Ignite 2.9 as well (is it ignored), my bad, we had increased it to 30G while testing crash issue. is it the root cause then? What should be the optimal DirectMemorySize, our UDP transmits about 300 MB of data per second. Should I keep it to 500 mb?

Comment: did not send updated logs with -XX:+DisableExplicitGC, there were multiple restarts. These 2 logs I had extracted for public posting, as it's difficult to ship files from exchange colo machines. Apologies. But thanks for above, will test it with optimal direct memorybuffer size with your suggested values.

Comment: Usually there is no need to specify DirectMemorySize explicitly so I don't know what is the optimal value.

Comment: Alright, I tried running service with 5 GB max JVM memory, memory went upto 6 GB, that itself is high (with DisableExplicitGC, DirectMemSize) removed, . Is there any forum where I could post the logs to you, or Ignite team - I could post further on this topic, and post the answer when I could get 2.10 working good as expected. We continue to run 2.9, and it takes 3 GB in the same environment. I reckon, there is some limit on comments in this forum.

Comment: You have `AlwaysPreTouch` option, which will force JVM to allocate its whole heap if I am not mistaken. Can you try removing it and see what happens?

Comment: Sure, I will try that. Exchange holiday tomm, can post the results by Friday. BTW same option is applied on 2.9 as well, based on suggestion on Ignite website. We prefer not to have long GC pauses (I am good with C#, I don't know either btw) : https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/perf-and-troubleshooting/memory-tuning